# Filter of records in oracle

Tags: regex, oracle, regex-negation

I have a sets of records in a table like

```
xyz_t
abc_y
pqr_12-11-2013
psq_1
App_tq2
xyzq_12-10-2014
lpqs_14-09-2012
llyt_23-09-2011
bytx_2
prdtc
```

I want output

```
pqr_12-11-2013
xyzq_12-10-2014
lpqs_14-09-2012
llyt_23-09-2011
```

I mean only those records which has date is suffix.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

```
select s from t 
where regexp_like(s, '_[[:digit:]]{1,2}-[[:digit:]]{1,2}-[[:digit:]]{4}$');
```

`[:digit:]` - any digit (you can also use `\d`)

`{4}` - four times

`{1,2}` - one or two times

`$` end of the string (by default the first carriage return is interpreted as the end)

Comment: Hi Thanks.
But in actual program its not returning all rows which has suffix _date.
Could you please help me again?

Comment: @Rubab Can you give an example of the string which is missed

Comment: Hi,I got the issue.Actually few records are like xyz_12-2-2013 or xyz_2-2-2013.So i mean date foramt is not everywhere same sa dd-mm-yyyy.Its some where as dd-m-yyyy or d-m-yyyy.Could you please look into this?

Comment: Thanks Friend.Now i got what actually i was looking.Thanks buddy.

Answer (score 1):

Use regular expression:

```
select your_column_name
from your_table
where REGEXP_LIKE(your_column_name, '.*\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}$')
```

Comment: you missed the underline before the date.

Comment: If you want to exclude the pattern like `xxx01-01-2014`, then you should prepend `_` to the regexp. Otherwise, it's not essential.